# NullPoinerException в RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android

Необходимо в обработчике нажатия запустить новую активити, изменив view компонеты, которые хранит ее xml представление.

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "NewsAdapter";
    private static ArrayList<Datum> mDataset;
    private static Context context;


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView testTextCV;
        private TextView testTextCV2;
        private ImageView imageViewCV;
        private TextView newsFullTitle;
        private TextView newsFullCreatedAt;
        private TextView newsFullContent;
        private ImageView newsFullImage;
        private static Datum newForFullDisplaying;


        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            testTextCV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.testTextCV);
            testTextCV2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.testTextCV2);
            imageViewCV = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCV);
            newsFullTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.newsFullTitle);
            newsFullCreatedAt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.newsFullCreatedAt);
            newsFullContent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.newsFullContent);
            newsFullImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.newsFullImage);

            context = v.getContext();

            v.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        public TextView getTestTextCV() {
            return testTextCV;
        }

        public TextView getTestTextCV2() {
            return testTextCV2;
        }

        public ImageView getImageCV() {
            return imageViewCV;
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
            newsFullTitle.setText("SomeTitle");
            newsFullContent.setText("SomeContent");
            //etc

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsFullScreenActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    }


    public NewsAdapter(ArrayList<Datum> myDataset) {
        this.mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    //Создание нового view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.one_news_carview, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");

        //Получение эемента из датасет в этой позиции и замена контента вью
        //этим элементом
        viewHolder.getTestTextCV().setText(mDataset.get(position).getTitle());
        viewHolder.getTestTextCV2().setText(mDataset.get(position).getUpdatedAt());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}


 public class NewsFullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.news_full_screen);
    }
}
```

При попытке установить значения

```
newsFullTitle.setText("SomeTitle");
newsFullContent.setText("SomeContent");
```

вылетает ошибка:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at game.normal.com.normalgame4.news.news.recycler.view.all.NewsAdapter$ViewHolder.onClick(NewsAdapter.java:78)

Очевидно что `findViewById` возвращает `null`. Кто-то может подсказать почему вьюхи хранят null если в конструкторе я их нашел?

Comment: `findViewById` в конструкторе может вернуть `null`

Comment: да, я понимаю, а почему это происходит?

Comment: Может быть дело в том, что вы не у того объекта вызываете `findViewById`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны в методе `onBindViewHolder` реализовывать такие функции как `onClick` и т.д.

перенесите их туда.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
     Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");

     viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
               newsFullTitle.setText("SomeTitle");
               newsFullContent.setText("SomeContent");
               //etc

               Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsFullScreenActivity.class);
               context.startActivity(intent);
            }
     });

     //Получение эемента из датасет в этой позиции и замена контента вью
     //этим элементом
     viewHolder.getTestTextCV().setText(mDataset.get(position).getTitle());
     viewHolder.getTestTextCV2().setText(mDataset.get(position).getUpdatedAt());

}
```

Comment: я уже решил проблему передачей нужного объекта в интенте и  сетя значения в onCreate самой активности, вроде работает) 
но всеравно спасибо)